# Does Deactivate/Reactivate of a SharePoint Feature Increment the Version?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a complex scenario which requires a timer job to run after content deployment to a SP 2010 site collection. The timer job automatically deactivates/reactivates a branding feature which is responsible for setting the master page for the site collection, among other things.

We have had several feature upgrades along the way, and neglected to call .Update() on the feature in that specific site collection. So all of the updated CSS, master page, page layouts etc. are out of date on that SC.

The strange part is that when I checked the version number of that feature in this SC, it shows as the latest version. The custom upgrade action clearly didn't run and update the files, because nobody called .Upgrade().

One of my colleagues suggested that the deactivate/reactivate process done by the timer job would update the version number, meaning that I can no longer call Upgrade()!

1. Is that true? Does a deactivate/reactivate cycle for a feature automatically update the feature version number?
2. Is there an easy way to fix this mess? Some way to decrement the version number programmatically, then call Upgrade()??

Answer (score 0):

On 1: No. Feature deactivating / activating does not trigger an update. See this article by Chris O' Brian: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html

> Feature upgrade does NOT happen automatically (including when the
>   Feature is deactivated/reactivated)! The only way to upgrade a Feature
>   is to call SPFeature.Upgrade(), typically in conjunction with one of
>   the QueryFeatures() methods. My tool which I’ll go on to talk about is
>   a custom application page which helps you with this part – note there
>   is no STSADM command, PowerShell cmdlet or user interface to do this
>   out-of-the-box.

Is your timer job cycling the feature activation with `Force`? Then, yes, it is triggering the feature upgrade/feature update see the following screenshot from `SPFeature.Activate` (see my yellow marking):

[image: SPFeature.Activate via ILSpy]

Why the feature version is incremented, I'm not sure. When you have a feature, install a new feature version and activate / deactivate, the feature version stays the same unless you run an Upgrade, see also this related question stating the same: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/feature-upgrading-question
I'm guessing your timer job is using `force`? Otherwise I'm not quite sure what is happening.

On 2: Don't know if it is possible to decrease the version number, but the safest way would be to just create a new version including a grand "clean up" feature receiver which sets everything correct, i.e. checks which steps of the feature upgrade have happened already (e.g. new list created, new content type added) and which haven't. Depending on that just execute the same steps again which have not executed yet. For the latter part you can fortunately use the existing code, so you would only need the "clean up" or checking code.

Comment: I know that the upgrade doesn't happen automatically, that wasn't the question. The question was does it automatically update the version number (without running the Upgrade() function), and I think the answer is NO looking at the decompiled source you posted.

The timer job isn't passing the force param so that's not it. I'm at a loss to explain why the version number is updated but the Upgrade() function doesn't seem to have been called.

As for #2, I think I'll just manually update all of the files and call it fixed. I'm more worried about ensuring this doesn't happen again.

Comment: I just did some testing and it seems that this code isn't the whole picture. I created a test upgrade solution with a custom upgrade action and updated the solution using PS. Then I checked the feature version for one of the webs where it's activated and it showed the correct 0.0.0.0 version number. Then I deactivated/reactivated the feature on that web and checked the version again in PS, and it was 1.2.0.0!! So somehow the deactivate/reactivate process updates the version number, even though the upgrade code hasn't run. This is a real bummer.

Comment: I discussed with a colleague. On feature activating/deactivating the newest feature version is assumed. There is no versioning of features, so SharePoint doesn't know "which version is activated at which level". There is only one feature definition and that states the correct version. The feature upgrade event receiver action is **only run** when using the `.Upgrade()` method. The declerative way to do updates (`VersionRange` and e.g. `ApplyElementManifest`) **is** being applied on activating/deactivating AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found that simply deactivating and reactivating the feature will increment the version number and completely screw up your upgrade! I even watched the update come through in the content database. As soon as you deactivate/reactivate the updated feature, the new version number pops into the content DB. Of course the upgrade doesn't actually run, it just increments the version number.

This means that if you then call .Upgrade() it won't work because SharePoint thinks it's already been upgraded!!

To fix this I updated the row in the content database to set the feature version back to 0.0.0.0 for that particular web and then I could run .Upgrade() just fine....but that's not exactly a supported solution. If anyone else has a better idea drop a reply.